# JAVA: Help understanding the correlation between a class's field and constructor

Tags: java

So I'm pretty much still a beginner, and I've been spending a lot time trying to truly understand the data structures and order of operations in Java, breaking down with very small seemingly simple programs. I'm having trouble deciphering why the compiler is rendering the result it does in the following code, I've created a lot of mini programs utilizing Jframes panels and ActionListener instances but now I find myself not understanding this, very small few lines of code:

```
public class Classname{

    static Classname object = new Classname(); 
    static String word = ("Word's Literal"); 

    public Classname(){
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
    }
}
```

Like I said, a VERY small seemingly simple program, the aspect I don't understand is the field, "Word". I understand that, although there's nothing in the main method, the compiler is going to read what's in the field, and in the field, we have object, which is a new instance of the class, and is also calling the constructor, hence we get an execution of the constructor's body. 
     That much is clear to me, however, what I don't understand is the fact that when you run this code, fieldletter executes as being equal to null. But when you remove the static invocation from the field, "word", it suddenly has a value in the constructor call and happily prints, "Word's Literal" This makes no sense to me. I understand the difference between static, where-by there is one existing instance of an element, and not declaring static to a field renders it non-static, so it can have many separate instances..but that still doesn't ring a bell as to why Word is equal to null when it's static in the field, and the value I give it rings true when it's non-static in the field. Can someone please explain this syntax to me? Thank you!

Comment: You mention "fieldletter", as in "fieldletter executes as being equal to null." What do you mean by that?

Comment: Static fields are initialized in order. By the time `object` is initialized and the constructor invoked, `word` has value `null` because it wasn't initialized yet. If you remove `static` from `word`, it becomes an instance field which gets initialized before the body of the constructor is executed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see your answer at first but you added to what fortytwo said and explained it well!!g In regards to fieldletter, sorry, I was switching back and forth between what I already had written in my IDE and on this forum, the field "word", was originally named fieldletter, but I changed it to word to make more sense in this post..

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the static fields is dependent of the order they are declared. When

```
static Classname object = new Classname();
```

is executed, `word` has not yet been initialized, and is consequently null. Try

```
static String word = ("Word's Literal");
static Classname object = new Classname();
```

and see what happens.

Removing the `static` from `static String word` makes it an instance varaiable, which will be instantiated before execution of the constructor body.

Is that clear?

Comment: Can you please explain it it detail?

Comment: @ forty-two:     VERY! So I understand now that a static field is dependent on order where-as an instance field if initialized within the field, will be read with what you defined it as anywhere.. I also noticed of course, that these same rules don't apply to a method. A method reads the value of a field variable regardless of being static or instance, because obviously you can't call a method in a field, so a method will always be after an initialization of the field. Thank you so much!!